# npm not installing packages even after proxy is set

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, proxy, npm

I am trying to set up a node js based application in one of our lab servers where connectivity to internet is achieved via a proxy. The box is running Ubuntu 13.10. I have configured the network proxy and I am able to connect to internet through Firefox. For `apt-get`, I have configured the proxy in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`. This is also working.

After installing node js, when I try to do `npm install -g <package>` it's giving me errors. I have configured the proxy for npm too. My .npmrc looks like this: (my proxy does not require userid/password).

```
registry = http://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy = http://<domain>:8080/
https-proxy = http://<domain>:8080
```

I have tried various options found in forums, but none seems to work for me. (Like setting `strict-ssl` to `false`, using `--without-ssl --insecure` option etc.)

This is the error I am getting currently:

```
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic
npm ERR! command "/home/<user>/apps/node-v0.10.26-linux-x86/bin/node" "/home/<user>/apps/node-v0.10.26-linux-x86/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "express"
npm ERR! cwd /home/<user>
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/<user>/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any idea, what's going wrong here? I'm stuck with this darn thing for the day ;-(

Thanks!

Comment: What is the path of your .npmrc file?  What does `P:\>npm config get https-proxy` and `npm config get proxy` output?

Comment: .npmrc is in my home directory (`/home/<user>`). When I get the properties via `npm config get`, I get the correct values. Had to resort to offline installation to get around this for now. Still no idea why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to get a resolution for this issue, but found a work around - I bundled the packages I require on my laptop and then resorted to offline installation on the lab box. Here is how to do that:

Take for example, `mongodb` node module. I have it installed on my laptop where I do the development. If you open the `package.json` file for mongodb module, the dependencies are listed with corresponding version numbers. Mine looks like this:

`"dependencies": {
    "bson": "0.2.5",
    "kerberos": "0.0.3"
  },`

Update the `package.json` file to include `"bundledDependencies"`. (the position shouldn't really matter, just that it should be at the same level, as a sibling of `"dependencies"` in the JSON tree). This is what you need to add:

`"bundledDependencies": [
    "bson",
    "kerberos"
  ],`

Now, while you are within your package's directory (where the `package.json` file is present), run the command `npm pack`. That will create a tgz file for you. In my case it created `mongodb-1.3.23.tgz`. Just copy this file to the box where you want to install it and run `npm install ./mongodb-1.3.23.tgz`. That should get you through. Since all dependencies are now bundled within this `.tgz` file, npm won't try to connect to internet for installing any of them.

However, I would still like to know what's going wrong with my internet based installation. That's still a mystery!